# How to use threads which will receive same data at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to create console application in c# which is going to connect to local push server and will receive messages from it.

I have created the application which is able to read response from push server for 'single' connection made by using following code:

```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.15.174/MvisumPushServer/PushServer.ashx?op=2&DeviceUniqueID=50211&ConnectionTimeout=30&ConnectionMechanism=Wifi&OSVersion=10&DeviceMake=Android&DeviceModel=sdk");

   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   Stream stream = null;
   stream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
   s = reader.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Now I want to do same thing for 5 or more connections from single program using threads.
These many connections should receive all messages individually and should display it to console. For example if 5 notifications are generated from push server on console total 25 alerts should be written i.e. each connection receiving each message from push server.I have tried it using Lock(this) but total 5 alerts are getting displayed on console.

Answer (score 0):

If it matters your approach is about a device which is turn on periodically. This means that if you want to test the server, you have to perform a poll by using a timer.
An array of timers calling a routine with the code you already have at specific or random intervals will do the job, as long as you use a thread safe Queue to enqueue the responses and separately dequeue them and write them on console. In addition this routine may accept different DeviceUniqueIDs (as parameter) if you connect a DeviceUniqueID to each timer (with another array of the same length).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is actually the lock.  I suspect some thread is acquiring the lock and then blocking on ReadLine and thus preventing the other threads from making progress.  Assuming WriteLine is thread safe, you should be able to execute your code above in five threads with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like your threading approach is responsible for the problem.  It sounds like your server is sending one event per connection (5 connections) rather than five events per connection.